# Can't pull latest source

Tags: github

I'm getting a very unhelpful message when I try to pull from git in team explorer:

[image]

I have nothing left to commit locally:

[image]

I could use some tips on where to start looking with this one, e.g. how to even find out what the two conflicts are (the error isn't clickable to drill or anything).

I have some untracked changes, but they are just package files such as the Entity Framework 6.1

Edit: git status:

> On branch dev
>   Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
>   and have 2 and 16 different commits each, respectively.
>     (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

When trying to git pull, it references files that are not showing up anywhere in vis studio team explorer to commit:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    packages/Modernizr.2.6.2/Content/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js
    packages/Respond.1.2.0/content/Scripts/respond.js
    packages/Respond.1.2.0/content/Scripts/respond.min.js
    packages/bootstrap.3.0.0/content/Content/bootstrap.css
    packages/bootstrap.3.0.0/content/Content/bootstrap.min.css
    packages/bootstrap.3.0.0/content/Scripts/bootstrap.js
    packages/bootstrap.3.0.0/content/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js
    packages/jQuery.1.10.2/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js
    packages/jQuery.1.10.2/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
    packages/jQuery.Validation.1.11.1/Content/Scripts/jquery.validate.js
    packages/jQuery.Validation.1.11.1/Content/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    Web/Web.config
    packages/elmah.corelibrary.1.2.2/elmah.corelibrary.1.2.2.nupkg
    packages/elmah.corelibrary.1.2.2/lib/Elmah.dll
```

Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting

Comment: Can you open git bash and run `git status` and show the output?

Comment: Done. I am mainly confused as to why it's outright failing instead of letting me go down the usual merge route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stash by running `git stash`, then do a `git pull`

Comment: Can't say I understand any of it, but thanks. Also I had to re-include the three bottom files even though I don't want them to be part of source control.

Comment: The stash just took all of the changes that hadn't been commited and saved them somewhere, resetting your environment to a state that had a common ancestor with your remote repo. Then, when you `git pull`, you merge all the commits up until the latest. If you needed anything that got stashed, just run `git stash pop`, and all those changes will be reapplied on top of your current directory. Here's some more information on stashing if you are interested: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing